# How to get previous intents in Dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have follow-up intents same here

```
Appointment
---Get Fullname
    ---Get Number Phone
        ---Get Address
            ---Yes
            ---No
```

Get Fullname has $fullname parameter

Get Number Phone has $phone

Get Address has $address

From Get Address, the response is a confirmed button.

In Yes intent, I design getting 'Yes' then switch to fulfillment. I can print information by using #GetFullName-followup.fullname, #GetNumberPhone-followup.phone, #GetAddress-followup.address in Yes intent.

```
function saveDataHandler(agent){
    const{
      fullname, phone, address
    } = agent.parameters;
    const data = [{
      Name: fullname,
      Phone: phone,
      Address: address
    }];
    axios.post('googlesheets', data);
  }
  
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Yes', saveDataHandler);
```

It doesn't save data into google sheets.

I try given value directly, it also isn't working

```
function saveDataHandler(agent){
    const{
      fullname, phone, address
    } = agent.parameters;
    const data = [{
      Name: "Bee",
      Phone: "000000",
      Address: "NN"
    }];
    axios.post('googlesheets', data);
  }
  
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Yes', saveDataHandler);
```

Comment: It looks like you have two questions here, so it isn't clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to get the parameters, or are you asking how to post them to a spreadsheet? Can you update your question to clarify this, and to clarify what the 'googlesheets' URL is supposed to be and do?

Comment: Add the previous intents parameters in the last intent and fetch its value from the context. Then you can fetch it using agent.parameters.